# Cannot found inserted document after delete index

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I write a simple test validate duplicates are not exist, like this:

```
@Test
public void testSameDataNotPushedTwice() throws Exception {
    // Do some logic
    // index contains es index name
    
    // adding this line fail the test
    // deleteOldData(esPersistence.getESClient(), index);
    esPersistence.insert(cdrData);
    esPersistence.insert(cdrData);

    SearchResponse searchResponse = getDataFromElastic(esPersistence.getESClient(), index);
    assertThat(searchResponse.getHits().getHits().length).isEqualTo(1);
}
```

As you can see I push data to ES and check hits length equals 1.

Test is passed when the delete line is in commnet.

Now, I want to make sure there is no data from others tests, therefore I want to delete the index before the insert. The `delete` method works but search response return 0 hits after the insert.

The delete index method:

```
public static void deleteOldData(RestHighLevelClient client, String index) throws IOException {
    GetIndexRequest request = new GetIndexRequest(index);
    boolean exists = client.indices().exists(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    if (exists) {
        DeleteIndexRequest deleteRequest = new DeleteIndexRequest(index);
        client.indices().delete(deleteRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Highlights:

- ES 7.6.2
- The data is exist in ES.
- Adding sleep not solve the problem (even for 10 seconds).
- The search is working (document is found) while debugging.

**Bottom line:** How can I perform delete index --> insert --> search and found the documents?

### Edit

Add insert to ES and GetSettingsRequest:

```
deleteOldData(esPersistence.getESClient(), index);
esPersistence.insert(testData);

GetSettingsRequest request = new GetSettingsRequest().indices(index);
GetSettingsResponse getSettingsResponse = esPersistence.getESClient().indices().getSettings(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

esPersistence.insert(testData);
```

[image]

Insert methods:

```
public boolean insert(List<ProjectData> projDataList) {
    // Relevant Lines
    BulkRequest bulkRequest = prepareBulkRequests(projDataList, esConfiguration.getCdrDataIndexName());
    insertBulk(bulkRequest)
}

private BulkRequest prepareBulkRequests(List<ProjectData> data, String indexName) {
    BulkRequest bulkRequest = new BulkRequest();
    for (ProjectData ProjectData : data) {
        String json = jsonParser.parsePojo(ProjectData);

        bulkRequest.add(new IndexRequest(indexName)
                .id(ProjectData.getId())
                .source(json, XContentType.JSON));
    }

    return bulkRequest;
}

private boolean insertBulk(BulkRequest bulkRequest) {
    try {
        BulkResponse bulkResponse = rhlClient.bulk(bulkRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

        if (bulkResponse.hasFailures()) {
            logger.error(buildCustomBulkFailedMessage(bulkResponse));
            return false;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.warn("Failed to insert csv fields. Error: {}", e.getMessage());
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that your index is refreshed after the first insert? What do you get when retrieving the [settings of the index](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-get-settings.html) created as a result of the insertion?

Comment: @Val, Thanks for your qucik repsonse, I add `GetSettingsRequest` and got an empty map, I edit the question and add a screenshot (GetSettingsRequest request = new GetSettingsRequest().indices(index);
GetSettingsResponse getSettingsResponse = esPersistence.getESClient().indices().getSettings(request, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);)

Comment: I'm interested in the JSON on the first line

Comment: @Val, Thanks again, the json itself is regular json, pushed by bulks. move the `GetSettingsRequest` after the first insert. Thanks again!

Comment: No, I meant the JSON that shows on the first line of your debug window

Comment: @Val I am sorry, but not sure I got you... the first line in the SettingsResponse is `{"automationcdrdata":{"settings":{"index":{"creation_date":"1589270087249","number_of_shards":"1","number_of_replicas":"1","uuid":"GHc9wg_FTn6sl1qPh4SmZg","version":{"created":"7060299"},"provided_name":"automationcdrdata"}}}}` do you mean for that? otherwise please guide me your steps, if you can...

Comment: Yes, that's what I wanted to see, if there was any `refresh_interval` being set in there. But that's not the case, so the default is `1s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a Speical thanks to David Pilato (from ES fourm) - need to refresh the index after the insert operation, like this:

```
client.indices().refresh(new RefreshRequest(index), RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

[link](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/cannot-found-inserted-document-after-delete-index/232225).